# how to split a column into comma seperated string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here  is sample dataframe and a is my column name.

```
    a   b   x
0   1   3   a
1   2   4   a
2   1   3   b
3   2   5   b
4   2   4   c
```

need a column unique values to be seperated in this way

```
required output: '1','2'
```

below is my code i'm getting like this

```
x=x1['id'].unique()
x2=','.join("\'"+str(i)+"\'" for i in x)

for this way of code 
i'm getting output some thing like this 
output:"'1','2'"

**2nd approach:**
x2=','.join("\'"+x1['id']+"\'"):

if i'm do this i'm getting the count of id has been increasing
```

i need to pass output into sql query like select * from abc where a in (x2) for that reason need output something like this

```
x2 -->'1','2'

i'm getting
x2--->" '1','2'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your first approach with f-strings to make things easier.

```
x2 =' ,'.join(f"'{str(i)}'" for i in x)

query = rf"""
SELECT
    *
FROM
    abc
WHERE
    a in ({x2})
"""
```

If you try `print(query)`, it gives

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    abc
WHERE
    a in ('1' ,'2')
```

Comment: getting same as previous "'1' ,'2'"

Comment: What happens when you rung `print(query)`, as I did in the answer? It prints out the output that I posted.

Comment: sql issue solved but this duplication still persists   ' ,'.join(f"'{str(i)}'" for i in x) for this line of code generating new values

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplication.